# ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool Max retries exceeded using pywebhdfs

Tags: hadoop, webhdfs, pyhdfs-client

Hi i am using pywebhdfs python lib. i am connecting EMR by calling and trying to create file on HDFS. I am getting below exception which seems irrelevant against what i am performing as i am not hitting any connection limit here. 
is it due to how webhdfs works

```
from pywebhdfs.webhdfs import PyWebHdfsClient
hdfs = PyWebHdfsClient(host='myhost',port='50070', user_name='hadoop')
my_data = '01010101010101010101010101010101'
my_file = 'user/hadoop/data/myfile.txt'
hdfs.create_file(my_file, my_data)
```

throws:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   HTTPConnectionPool(host='masterDNS', port=50070): Max retries exceeded
>   with url:
>   /webhdfs/v1/user/hadoop/data/myfile.txt?op=CREATE&user.name=hadoop
>   (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 115] Operation now in progress',))

Comment: Perhaps this may be of some assistance: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://91r.net/ask/34259099.html&prev=search. Seems to be regarding entering separate host entries to enable getting round the same URL issue causing the exception. Not a great solution to the core issue, but it may help you get round it, at least.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well. I found that for some reason the call to:

**send(self, request, stream=False, timeout=None, verify=True, cert=None, proxies=None):**

is passed a timeout of 0, and that causes **send** to throw a

**MaxRetryError**

Bottom line, I found if you just set timeout = 1, it works fine:

**hdfs = PyWebHdfsClient(host='yourhost', port='50070', user_name='hdfs', timeout=1)**

Hope this works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting the namenode solved this problem for me several times.

```
hdfs namenode -format
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the status of your connection. Run below command to see if the webhdfs port works from your host:

```
netstat -an | grep 50070 | grep LIST
```

Please note:

- If SSL is enabled then port would be 50470.
- `hdfs namenode -format` should not run from the node because it formats your namenode and you loose everything.

Answer (score -1):

maybe, webhdfs service is not running on the host that you specify. you may check your cluster to see which host is running webhdfs service.